# Handling GET with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I have my .htaccess file redirecting all URLs to index.php?url=$1 as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

But when the url is authenticate?code=blahblahblah the code= part is not pulled in, therefore meaning I cannot access it when handling the page D: Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`[QSA]`](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+rewriterule+%5BQSA%5D) flag then.

Answer (score 1):

use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]` instead