# htaccess get code and redirect with php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Ex:

If we entered these url (Like This site)

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139779/` or `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139779`

Its automatically redirect to this url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139779/handling-get-with-htaccess`

I want to get this code `(10139779)` from `url` and redirect to full url. Someone go to full url how to get this code `(10139779)`

Edit :

I created htaccess file like this.

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

Now i want to give video title to url after video id  Like this `www.example.com/16056/video-title`

```
load.php

<?php
echo $_GET['code'];

//I can get video title from php then how to give to url it?
?>
```

I can get code this from `www.example.com/16566` but i can't get code this from this url `www.example.com/16566/video-title`

after id `/` link was doesnt work. how to fixed it

Comment: please check my post edited.

Comment: Seen your codes. What is the content of the PHP? Also, only `.htaccess` can't read the title of your "video". Must be done in PHP

Comment: check last edited. if u can please help me.. thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Send out a location header for the correct URL. (*load.php*:)

```
<?php
    header('Location: /videos/'.$_GET['code'].'/'.getTheVideoTitle($_GET['code']));
?>
```

There is nothing you can do in .htaccess to get the video title, so php must do it.

Also, for .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/*$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

This makes it match slash(s) after the URL. If you also want it to match the title after the URL, make it:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+) ./load.php?code=$1
```

Comment: if u can please check last edited. now u can understand this. thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you want help getting the video title?

Comment: after /(slash) link doesnt work (example.com/165655/ << this one)

Comment: if u can check this url http://www.col3negmovie.com/test/hta/16589   now this is work but this is not work http://www.col3negmovie.com/test/hta/16589/

Comment: your edited post good. but after /(slash) i am typed something now its not work :(

Comment: Did you apply all the changes I mentioned? I can't think of any more problems…

Comment: please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889268/htaccess-rewriterule-and-after-slash-want-to-type-something

Comment: Edited. The last example will match the title after.

Comment: @bjb568 this code is unsafe. if the `$_GET['code']` is not set, this code fails.

Comment: @Raptor Well, what would you like it to do?

Comment: see my answer. Also, bear in mind that there should be a space after the `Location:`, and for consistency & code safety, all `header("Location: $url");` must follow by a `exit;`, though it is not a must in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an additional update of @bjb568's answer, which handles exceptions.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $code = (int)$_GET['code'];
  $url = '/videos/' . $code . '/' .getTheVideoTitle($code);
} else {
  $url = '404_page_not_found.php'; // or redirect visitors to homepage
}
header("Location: $url");
exit;
?>
```

Also, this prevents someone intentionally "hack" the link by entering strings with escape character & crash the code. *(Of course, it's developer's duty to validate the input in the `getTheVideoTitle()` function)*

Comment: My code would handle that perfectly fine. It would go to `/videos//null` and that would 404.

Comment: `.htaccess` above does not mention anything about 404 page. Also, what if the input character is escape characters?

Comment: Then nothing. Redirecting to a random page is the worst that can happen, and given that the user is probably trying to hack you, that doesn't matter.

Comment: If the GET variable is not set, there will be a warning posted on screen if `display_errors` is enabled, which makes `header("Location: ");` fails, as header is already sent.

Comment: `'Location: /videos/'.$_GET['code'].'/'.getTheVideoTitle($_GET['code'])` --> `'Location: /videos//'` I don't see where the warning would come from.

Comment: @bjb568 that's a very bad idea to let uncontrollable behavior to be executed. The "hacker" can even insert codes into the variable. If the code is unset, PHP will issue **Undefined index** Notice

Comment: Of course. The hacker can insert anything he wants by typing into his URL bar. But that doesn't make anything more risky. The only think happening here is the value (plus the vid title which you should definitely be cautious about) is echoed back in a header. There is no random `eval()`ing of `$_GET`. An undefined index notice is not the end of the world, and I've never seen one before as I don't bother showing notices.

Comment: @bjb568 that's a very bad practice of not handling warning message, and the warning message will block the redirection, as it will raise an error: **header already sent**. For the codes inserted to URL, you can read more about XSS in Google. Still not convinced?

Comment: A notice is not a warning. A warning is something to be fixed. A notice is something to be ignored. I do not show notices, so it won't give the "headers already sent" error. XSS is about "enabling attackers to inject client-side script into Web pages viewed by other users." which is irrelevant to this.

Comment: In any case, this answer is a comment on my answer, not a new answer itself.