# htaccess rewriterule and after slash want to type something

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my htaccess file

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/*$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

load.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['code'];
?>
```

if i typed `www.example.com/1995` or `www.example.com/1995/` php showing `1995` only. but after slash(/) type something url doesnt work. ex : `www.example.com/1995/video-title`

i want to if we type `www.example.com/1995/video-title` php showing `1995` only.

how to do it? help me. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/*$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

with

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.*)$ ./load.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/*$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

should allow `www.example.com/1995`, `www.example.com/1995/`, `www.example.com/1995/video-title`, or `www.example.com/1995/video-title/` have `1995` printed in the php page.

Comment: now ok but www.example.com/16555 not work :( ... work only with / and after slash any type

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer code. You need both `RewriteRules`

Comment: if can please help me for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889850/htaccess-get-page-pagination-with-slash