# htaccess get page pagination with slash

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

www.example.com/category/ .htaccess

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(.*)$ ./load.php?code=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/*$ ./load.php?code=$1
```

load.php

```
<?php

$code = $_GET['code'];

echo $code.'<br/>';

echo $_GET['page'];

?>
```

www.example.com/category/`16598` << this is `'code'`. its showing with php `echo $_GET['code'];` But how to show `'page'` 
www.example.com/category/16598/video-title/`2` << this is `'page'` number.. how to show in with php `echo $_GET['page'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/hta/

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?code=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?code=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: oops... friend at this link doesnt work :( http://www.col3negmovie.com/test/hta/4665/sihina-cinderella

Comment: But there is no page# in this url. What should be internal url for this?

Comment: its category only. check this url http://www.col3negmovie.com/test/hta/4665/sihina-cinderella  sihina-cinderella is category name in this url http://www.col3negmovie.com/test/hta/4665/sihina-cinderella/2  2 is page number like page 2 3 4 5

Comment: after hta directory haven't any files

Comment: thanks... if u can please edit for this link `http://www.col3negmovie.com/test/hta/4665/isuru-gineth/page/2` i want to know whats the change it

Comment: `http://col3negmovie.com/test/hta/1655/isuru-gineth/page` this url is doesnt work. i dont want to show 404 page and show only same echo.. if u can fix it.. thanks..

Comment: You cannot keep changing requirements like this via comments section. Look at what you asked in your question and what this answer has become. Finally `/test/hta/1655/isuru-gineth/page` is an invalid URI since it doesn't have a page # after page.